# How to render listing for multiple elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Looking for solution to render `const days = ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 5"];` to `<div className="segment">`. Does it possible to make render listing for the input label elements.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/536wmpj3mp

```
export class Segment extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const days = ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 5"];
    return (
      <div className="segment">
        <input type="radio" id="day-1" name="day" value="Tay 1" />
        <label className="segment-button" htmlFor="day-1">
          day 1
        </label>
        <input type="radio" id="day-2" name="day" value="Tay 2" />
        <label className="segment-button" htmlFor="day-2">
          day 2
        </label>
        <input type="radio" id="day-3" name="day" value="Tay 3" />
        <label className="segment-button" htmlFor="day-3">
          day 3
        </label>
        <input type="radio" id="day-4" name="day" value="Tay 4" />
        <label className="segment-button" htmlFor="day-4">
          day 4
        </label>
        <input type="radio" id="day-5" name="day" value="Tay 5" />
        <label className="segment-button" htmlFor="day-5">
          day 5
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map` elements like :

```
import React from "react";

export class Segment extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const days = ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 5"];

    return (
       <div className="segment">
       {
         days.map((d, i) => {
          return(
            <div>
              <input type="radio" id={`day-${i + 1}`} name="day" value={`Tay ${i + 1}`} />
              <label className="segment-button" htmlFor={`day-${i}`}>{d}</label>
            </div>
           )
         })
        }
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: there is an error when apply your answer which is `ReferenceError
$ is not defined`

Comment: Try `'day-' + 1` within your console.

Comment: @ReyHaynes the things is that `const days` can't change because it is coming form API

Comment: @ReyHaynes And in what is it an issue for the script, I don't understand ?

Comment: @Striped Sorry, didn't see the `i` for some reason. This should work.

Comment: @ReyHaynes final result coming like this `<div class="segment"></div>`

Comment: @Striped The bracket was missing

Comment: @Muhammed Sorry for the missing brackets and thanks for the edit.